# Loop through array with php

Tags: php, arrays

For some reason i can't loop through this array with PHP.
I want too loops through and echo title.

This is the array

```
Array (
[data] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [company_id] => 1
                [title] => Software Developer
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [company_id] => 2
                [title] => Accountant
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [company_id] => 3
                [title] => Insurance salesman
            )

    )
```

)

This is my code

```
    foreach ($positions as $position) {
     echo $position->title;
}
```

Comment: See how you have an innerArray `data`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use as array and go one level more

```
foreach ($positions['data'] as $position) {
 echo $position['title'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
foreach ($positions['data'] as $position) {
     echo $position['title'];
}
```