# Laravel 5.0 can't parse array to view

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, controller

Can't parse array to view.

Here is the array

```
 Array (
    [positions] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [company_id] => 1
                    [title] => Software Developer
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [company_id] => 2
                    [title] => Accountant
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [company_id] => 3
                    [title] => Insurance salesman
                )
        )
)
```

this is the controller

```
$data = array(
    'positions' => $newarray['data']
);
return view('mypage', $data);
```

and this is the view where i try to echo the title

```
@foreach($positions as $position)
{{ $position->title }}<br>
@endforeach
```

i get this error in the view "Trying to get property of non-object"

Answer (score 2):

```
@foreach($positions as $position)
  {{ $position['title'] }}<br>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I don't know why are you getting upvotes, but your code will definitely won't work for two reasons. Because OP passes `$data` array in the view and he has broken code anyway.

Comment: The code is almost OK. But what will happend if key does'nt exists? I made small change in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36934256/loop-through-array-with-php), but if it'll be helpful, here it is.

```
@foreach($data['positions'] as $position)
{{ $position['title'] }}<br>
@endforeach
```

Also, you should change:

```
$data = array(
    'positions' => $newarray['data']
);
```

to something like:

```
$data = array(
    'positions' => $someDataArray;
);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all format your array properly, like this:

```
$positions = array
(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'company_id' => 1,
        'title' => 'Software Developer'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'company_id' => 2,
        'title' => 'Accountant'
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'company_id' => 3,
        'title' => 'Insurance salesman'
    )
);
```

Pass data to view:

```
$data = array(
    'positions' => $positions
);
return view('mypage', $data);
```

Now you can echo title like following:

```
@foreach($positions as $position)
    {{ $position['title'] }}<br>
@endforeach
```